# Django search not showing results

Tags: python, django

So I was trying to set up the search view for a model. But I think I am doing something wrong. Maybe I pass arguments wrong ?

```html
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        results = Course.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
    else:
        results = Course.objects.all()
    context = {
        'results': results,
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you define "not showing results"? Is it not returning any? Are they not rendering? etc

Comment: Question was answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you dont need use Q so remove Q and for better result you should check if q is ''.

```html
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query and q != '':
        results = Course.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
    else:
        results = Course.objects.all()
    context = {
        'results': results,
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/index.html', context)
```